# How does yelp monocle work

Tags: android, yelp

I was wondering how the Yelp monocle works. It a cool feature , especially in terms of augmented reality. So I know they access GPS and compass data. And they have data about places nearby like hotels and bars etc. But how do they calculate the orientation w.r.t each other in real time, as I rotate my device. So if my device is pointing east and theres a pizza place to the north. I rotate my device to north. Now how does it know that I'm facing a pizza place here.  What is the crucial bit of information being used to calculate this ?

I am thinking of developing similar kind of app for android. Please let me know how I can approach this ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you know where you are, you know where you are facing and where your target is, you can calculate the rest. It's basic trigonometry.